# User input array in Function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, parameters

I am trying to figure out how I can put this code in a function, so I can call it back in my main, but nothing is working. I am quite new to programming, thanks in advance! (So the goal is to let the user input numbers and the highest one gets picked out).

```
for (z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    cin >> array[z];


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > temp)
            temp = array[i];
    }

}
```

Comment: "Nothing is working" is not a useful problem description. Besides, the shown code in this question fails to meet the requirements for a [mcve]; as such no answer will be possible.

Comment: You've barely described your problem. You need to explicitly state what your problem is.

Comment: Dear Sam, I tried putting it in a function but I get errors with either the function notation or it wont calculate the highest number. And for your last criteria, I dont believe there is a need to expand my code by declaring the variables. The problem is that this piece of code will not succesfully execute once you put it in a function. Sorry for the bad problem description my English sucks. Thanks for the fast replies.

Comment: `temp` starts out as *what* ?? (see why you provide [MCVE's](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? to avoid having to ask questions like that). And do you really want to march a comparison loop through elements *you haven't even loaded yet* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like this should be two different "for" loops

you forgot to declare z, temp and array[]

EDIT: don't forget if you initialize array[] within the function you need to include the aggregate

try this:

```
int z, i;
int temp = 0;
int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

for (z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    cin >> array[z];
}


for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    if (array[i] > temp)
        temp = array[i];
}
```

this function would take no arguments, so you would declare it and call it as "function()"

SECOND EDIT: i was actually able to get a function like this to work, and it would look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void function();

int main() {
    cout << "enter 10 numbers: " << endl;

    function();

    return 0;
}

void function () {
    int z, i;
    int temp = 0;
    int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    for (z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    cin >> array[z];
    }


    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (array[i] > temp)
            temp = array[i];
    }

    cout << "your largest number is: " << temp;
}
```

good luck out there man

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you so much for this! My mistake was that I tried to put the array in the function parameters. Thanks once again.